# Grow div height to show all contents with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a very simple HTML preview pane as the user types in HTML.  Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xnPu7/1/).

It's very simple in execution.  Take the value of the text area, make it the HTML of the div next to it.

```
$('#message-preview').html($('#message').val());
```

The issue I'm running into, is that the preview pane, needs to grow height wise in order to accommodate all of the HTML that is being input into the left text area.  I notice (as I'm typing this) that SO already does this in their preview panes.  Is there an easy way to adjust heights of things to their inner contents while also having them next to each other?

Comment: Be aware that certain browsers will not expand the document to accomodate elements that overflow. For example if you grow a DIV outside of the bottom of the page, some browsers will not expand the page, which means there will be no scroll bar to goto the bottom of the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
position:absolute;
```

to

```
position:relative;float:right;
```

so it looks like this:

```
<div id="message-preview" class="well" style="position: relative; right: 0; width: 310px;float:right;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnPu7/2/

Comment: yes, but be careful with float:right; as the element will go as far right as possible. so you might make a <div class="wrapper"> arround those elements with a given width

Comment: your welcome, also sorry forgot to mention, height:100%; also is not needed. as you can see in the fiddle. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css approach from caramba or use the following javascript approach:

```
$('#message-preview').height($('#message-preview').offsetHeight());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnPu7/7/

Answer (score -1):

Because of the way that you have nested the message-preview in the fieldset and set the overflow to hidden, it will only ever be the height of the fieldset and will be constricted by the height thereof.

You can get around the problem by removing the overflow property of the fieldset and by setting the height of the fieldset to auto. This means the fieldset and the message-preview will be able to grow as needed.

```
fieldset {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#message-preview {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 310px;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It isn't because i just proved it in the fiddle.